# Sass won't compile because of an "invisible" error

Tags: sass

I am implementing compass to a already existing project which has a CSS with over 3800 lines.

This is the error it fires:

```
>>> Change detected at 19:47:43 to: style.scss
    error sass/style.scss (Line 3807: Invalid CSS after "​": expected "{", was "")
overwrite css/style.css
```

This is from line 3800:

```
.shake:hover {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
        
}
.shake.inline{
    display:inline-block 
}
```

Any idea of what am I missing here?

[image]

​-sassbin-

http://sassbin.com/gist/7324262/

-EDIT-

By removing all whitespaces:

line 3800:

```
.shake:hover {display:block;position:relative;}.shake.inline{display:inline-block;}​
```

Error changed to:

```
overwrite css/style.css 
>>> Change detected at 20:11:12 to: style.scss
    error sass/style.scss (Line 3800: Invalid CSS after "...line-block;}​": expected "{", was "")
```

Comment: Semi-colon after "inline-block"?

Comment: Not enough code here to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @PaulTomblin Tried, and error persist (but right before a `}` there shouldn't be a need.. i think)

Comment: @cimmanon check update with sassbin :)

Comment: Did you already try to remove the whitespace between `.shake:hover` and `{`? Maybe it's not a regular space but some other character (like tab, protected space, ...) that messes with SASS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your sassbin, it is actually showing you where the problem is.  There is a hidden character after the last closing curly brace, and it happens to look like a space or newline (sassbin displays it as a middot).

Comment: Nice catch! I had to delete the last curly, it wouldn't let me delete it if not.. thanks! (but the cursor would stop there for one keypress)